# native DLL working fine in windows XP and trowing System.DllNotFoundException in windows 7 or later

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, native, setup-deployment, dllregistration

I have a windows XP dev environment for C# application project combination with native DLL. Now I am trying to migrate to Windows7 using last visual studio 2015.

My problem is native DLL is trowing System.DllNotFoundException in windows7 dev environment, so it means I cannot create setup file with enhancements and new features.

Note: I got old windows xp setup file that will install in windows 7. same native DLL work perfectly fine, if that old setup file is installed.

I have no clue how setup file was created but it was created with [wise installation studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wise_Solutions)

The same native DLL files working after old application install and native DLL are not working in dev environment and giving  System.DllNotFoundException.

I tried with elevated permissions but no luck.
I am thinking of possible solutions one DLL registration I have no idea how to do that.

Any suggestion is well come

Thanks

Comment: Does the exception specify which DLL is not found? It maybe the DLL you are trying to access has dependencies on other DLLs that you do not have on you Windows 7 PC. There may be some suggestions her that help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093485/system-dllnotfoundexception-unable-to-load-dll-on-window-2003

Comment: Is the Windows 7 installation 64bit? If so, it is possibly trying to find a 64bit version of the native dll but not finding it. Though this is off the top of my head and I doubt it is the issue, but worth checking

Comment: Surely the installer provides a DLL that this DLL needs to get its job done.  It is not very clear why you are trying to avoid using the installer, it is always the recommended way to deploy somebody else's code, especially so when they don't pick up the telephone.

Comment: @HansPassant if it is not working in dev environment how it will work installer and in fact I tried with InstallShield and same issue came.

Comment: @PriestofPsi Thanks for you reply but the problem is on both 32bit and 64bit windows 7